# Working with many data points in ECharts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I need help to improve the number of points displayed on the chart line.
With the current code, for 100000 points, only 20 drawn in the graph line.

```
var elements = new Array(100000);

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i] = i;
}

var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
var option = {
    title: {
        text: 'ECharts entry example'
    },
    tooltip: {},
    legend: {
        data:['Sales']
    },
    xAxis: {
        data: elements
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
        name: 'Sales',
        type: 'line',
        data: elements
    }]
};
myChart.setOption(option);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to modify the xAxis for this. You should take a look at the [axisTicks](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#xAxis.axisTick), and play around with the `interval` option. It either supports `auto`, a number or a function.

---

Alternatively, you can also manually show/hide the datapoints, by telling the data elements to display them, but maybe this only works when there's an axis tick available.

For displaying *every* datapoint, set `showAllSymbol` to true in the series data.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Sales',
    type: 'line',
    showAllSymbol: true,
    data: elements
}]
```

However, 20.000 datapoints may be a lot, so you can also create an interval by setting `showSymbol` within the data elements

```
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i] = {
        value: i,
        symbol: (i % 100 === 0) ? 'circle' : 'none'
    }
}
```

This will set `showSymbol` to true for every 100th iteration. You may have to combine this with `showAllSymbol: true` in the series data to work properly.

*Note: `%` is the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/modulus-operator-decrementjavascript)*

Comment: Sorry for my terribly late reply, i'm new here, anyway your solution
helped me a lot, thank you so much!